# Error setting scrollFactor on FlxSprite after update to HaxeFlixel 3.3.0

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I just finished updating my HaxeFlixel install to 3.3.0 and after ironing out all the other upgrade changes I am still getting one error I can't find any explanation for. I am setting the `scrollFactor` property on the `FlxSprite`s that make up my background elements, and had no problem with it before 3.3.0. I can't seem to find any references to that property changing with the update.

Here is the relevant code where I am setting the property:

```
//Setup bg
var bg:FlxSprite;
var scrollFactor:FlxPoint;
for (i in 0...loader.bgArray.length){
    bg = new FlxSprite(0, 0, loader.bgArray[i][0]);
    scrollFactor = new FlxPoint(
        Std.parseFloat(loader.bgArray[i][1]),
        Std.parseFloat(loader.bgArray[i][2]));
    bg.scrollFactor = scrollFactor;
    add(bg);
}
```

Here is my output from haxelib list:

> flixel: [3.3.0]
>  hxcpp: [3.1.30]
>  lime-tools: [1.4.0]
>  lime:
>   [0.9.7]
>  openfl-html5: [1.4.0-beta]
>  openfl-native: [1.4.0]
>   openfl-samples: [1.3.0]
>  openfl: [1.4.0]

When I run lime test flash in my project folder with the above snippet I get:

> source/PlayState.hx:54: characters 3-33 : Cannot access field or
>   identifier scrollFactor for writing

Line 54 is the one where I am setting `bg.scrollFactor`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about notices about this update, but indeed the current situation is that `scrollFactor` accessors are `(default, null)`, so there is no chance you could set it up like that.

It also isn't even the most proper way to do that, since in HaxeFlixel `FlxPoint`s could and mostly should be pooled, so you would usually use not new `FlxPoint(x, y)`, but `FlxPoint.get(x, y)` which will make your code run much faster.

Anyhow, down to your current situation, just use

```
bg.scrollFactor.set(
  Std.parseFloat(loader.bgArray[i][1]),
  Std.parseFloat(loader.bgArray[i][2])
);
```

instead of

```
scrollFactor = new FlxPoint(
  Std.parseFloat(loader.bgArray[i][1]),
  Std.parseFloat(loader.bgArray[i][2])
);
bg.scrollFactor = scrollFactor;
```

and it will work perfectly (and faster).